# React hooks error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used to have a function component act as a page:

```js
export default function NormalList(props) {
    const pageSize = 20;
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState(null);
    const [creditNotes, setCreditNotes] = useState(() => getCreditNoteList());
    const [ordering, setOrdering] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => getCreditNoteList(), [page, searchString, ordering]);

    function getCreditNoteList() {
        API.fetchCreditNoteList({
            account_id: props.customerId, page, page_size: pageSize, searchString, ordering
        }).then(data => {
            setCreditNotes(data);
        });
    }
    return (<>{creditNotes.results.map(record => <...>}</>)
}
```

And this has been running fine, but recently I need to wrap around `NormalList` with `ListPage` component:

```js
export default function ListPage(props) {
    const customerId = props.match.params.customer_id;
    return (<div>...<div><NormalList/></div></div>)
}
```

Then all the sudden I am getting this error `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`

It seems to me that `setCreditNotes(data)` inside `getCreditNoteList` is causing the error, but I don't know why.

Comment: You should perform your side effects i.e data fetching inside a useEffect hook

Comment: Sorry I am don't quite understand what you meant?

Comment: Added an explanation hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

So there are a couple of things you need to fix. First of all you should remove your function call from the useState function, you should only perform your side effects inside a useEffect hook see [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

The next thing is whenever you decide to use the dependency array to your useEffect hook you should include all the dependencies of useEffect i.e all the props, state including functions inside your function component that you used inside your useEffect hook. So the Rule of Thumb is **Never Lie About Your Dependencies!** otherwise you will shoot yourself in the foot.

So the easiest option is to move your **getCreditNoteList** function inside your useEffect hook and add all the dependencies of your useEffect hook to the dependency array.

```js
export default function NormalList({ customerId }) {
    const pageSize = 20;
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState(null);
    const [creditNotes, setCreditNotes] = useState({});
    const [ordering, setOrdering] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {

      function getCreditNoteList() {
        API.fetchCreditNoteList({
            account_id: customerId, 
            page, 
            page_size: pageSize, 
            searchString, 
            ordering
        }).then(data => {
            setCreditNotes(data);
        });
      }

      getCreditNoteList(),

       // add ALL! dependencies
    }, [page, searchString, ordering, pageSize, customerId]))

    return (
       <> </>
    )
}
```

**Second Option**
If you want to use the **getCreditNoteList** function elsewhere and want to keep it outside your useEffect hook you can do that by wrapping your **getCreditNoteList** logic inside the useCallback hook as shown below and add the function to your dependency array inside your useEffect hook for reasons i mentioned earlier.

```js
export default function NormalList({ customerId }) {
    const pageSize = 20;
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState(null);
    const [creditNotes, setCreditNotes] = useState({});
    const [ordering, setOrdering] = useState(null);

    const getCreditNoteList = useCallback(() => {
        API.fetchCreditNoteList({
            account_id: customerId, 
            page, 
            page_size: pageSize, 
            searchString, 
            ordering
        }).then(data => {
            setCreditNotes(data);
        });
     // the function only changes when any of these dependencies change
    },[page, searchString, ordering, pageSize, customerId])

    useEffect(() => {

      getCreditNoteList(),

    },[getCreditNoteList])

    return (
       <> </>
    )
}
```

Comment: cool I will give a try tomorrow, the docs are not very clear about using side effect inside the useEffect function

Comment: I followed your option 1, and now its complaining the `props.match` being undefined in the outer `ListPage` component.

Comment: @JamesLin  is the ```ListPage``` component a parent to the ```NormalList```

Comment: Also I added customerId into the array now I get the original error...

Comment: Yes `ListPage` is parent of `NormalList`

Comment: Sounds like thats where the error is originating, can you add a snippet of the code in the ```ListPage```, because everything in ```NormalList``` should work just fine. I need to see where you are passing the ```props.match``` prop

Comment: Okay i went over your code in ```ListPage```, so the code in ```NormalList``` should work as it is. I assume you are getting the ```props.match``` from ```React-Router``` right? So to fix this bug try to first step is to ```console.log(props)``` inside ```ListPage``` and see if you get ```undefined``` for ```props.match.params.customer_id```.

Comment: Ps, Comment out lines 27 to line 40 from the pastebin you linked as you do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207617/discussion-between-james-lin-and-chitova263).

Answer (score 1):

OK My problem was that I had 2 issues with importing the elements, first being pycharm cleverly automatically imported them wrong, and secondly being I didn't import one of the component at all.

I wish the error message could be a bit more specific than "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render".

Also I tested I didn't need to move function body `getCreditNoteList` inside `useEffect`.

Thanks to @chitova263 for spending the time to help out.